# cargar fragment sin dejarlo en la fila

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation

estoy usando el componente navigation en android studio, estoy armando un formulario de registro, necesito cargar los fragment pero sin dejarlo en la fila de fragments cargados, así cuando el usuario presione el botón atrás este no vuelva a aparecer.

Probé usar NavOptions pero no logro hacer lo que quiero.

```
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.action_solicitarViajeElegirDestino_to_solicitarViajeStepTwo, true).build()
            Navigation.findNavController(view as View).navigate(R.id.solicitarViajeStepTwo,bundle,navOptions)
```

Em la imagen que adjunto, muestra como los fragment se van cargando en secuencia con la navegación interna de la app.
Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario va hacia atrás con el botón del celu, pase del fragment 5 al 3 sin pasar por el 4 , a diferencia de cuando se cargaron que pasaron 3 -> 4 -> 5

[image: secuencia carga de fragments]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, a que te refieres con " fila de fragments ", te sugiero agregar mayor información a tu pregunta, revisa [ask] , saludos.

Comment: Editada. gracias.

Comment: Me refería a la secuencia de carga de los mismos, quiero que al volver no cargue uno que estaba cargado anteriormente

Comment: Pero como estas agregando los Fragments, se agregan al Backstack, es importante agregar el código de como se agregan